# Abstract type in Julia and member variables

Tags: julia

I am very confused as to whether `abstract` types in Julia can have member variables (like virtual classes in C++). I am sure the docs mention it but I cannot find it!

I tried something like:

```
abstract AbstractR
  source
end
```

And now I have a concrete implementation as:

```
type RR <: AbstractR
end

function loadSource(reg::RR, x::AbstractString)
  println("Hello")
end
```

However, when I try to load the module, I have:

> ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: source not
>   defined

So is it that abstract type is just a type name and nothing else? Also, why did the language designers decide to not support member variables (if that is indeed the case). Also, I do not then really see the point of having an `abstract` type anyway...

**EDIT**

**Module file**

```
module TestProj
export AbstractR
export RR
include("generic.jl")
include("rr.jl")
end
```

**generic.jl**

```
abstract AbstractR
  source
end
```

**rr.jl**

```
type RR <: AbstractR
end

function loadSource(reg::RR, x::AbstractString)
  println("Hello")
end
```

Comment: What Julia version are you on?

Comment: @miguelraz 0.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least the way I understand it is that abstract types are intended to serve as "nodes" and as such are not themselves instantiateable (sp?). As such they allow you organise concrete types into hierarchies & provide an easy way for methods to dispatch on any of a group of concrete types.

I think the docs explain this [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#abstract-types).

(With this the error msg should make sense as well?)

Comment: This is correct. Abstract types don't have member variables. If the OP is interested in the reasoning behind the type system design, that is explained in the docs.
The most commonly asked question by new users of julia (or any language) is why the designers did not design it the way they did in the language the new user came from. The answer is that it is a different language. You may need to think about code design in a different way, but that is actually why you have the new language to begin with. Generally, trying to learn to do things in Julian is the most productive approach.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard  I get that. I am also aware of the biases one carries due to past experiences. It is still good to know the thought process behind the design. Back to the question, I understand that abstract types cannot be instantiated (and this is similar to other languages) but what I missed was that they cannot have member variables either.

Comment: @Luca cool didn't mean to sound annoying :-) I think a key thing to realize (and maybe you already do) is that because of dispatch, abstract types can have methods - just not variables. So in OO parlance, the purpose of abstract types is to inherit methods. Because the methods live outside the types, though, the methods shared by different nodes in the type hierarchy can be finetuned with really great detail.

Comment: The lack of inheritance of variables is very commonly discussed: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/workaround-for-traditional-inheritance-features-in-object-oriented-languages/1195 , https://discourse.julialang.org/t/oop-in-julia-inherit-from-parametric-composite-type/1841 , https://discourse.julialang.org/t/some-clarifications-and-best-practices-on-the-oo-model-in-julia/693

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard You were not annoying :-) Thanks for these links. I am really starting to like Julia now. Spend the whole weekend coding and have a much better idea of the philosophy behind it. Some I agree with, some I do not. But overall, it has been a positive experience. I also managed to port some of my python code over and got pretty good speedups right out of the box. I think I will take all my scientific computing work over to Julia. See how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a module then?
Perhaps you must import stuff first. 
Could you post the entirety of the code?